# Prove $\underset{r\to 0}{\lim}\int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z}dz=2i\pi f(0)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits

Given $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ continuous at $0$. 
Prove $\underset{r\to 0}{\lim}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz=2i\pi f(0)$

I've manage to show that $\gamma(t)=re^{it},t\in[0,2\pi]$
$\underset{r\to 0}{\lim}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz=\underset{r\to 0}{\lim}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f(re^{it})}{re^{it}}ire^{it}dt=\underset{r\to 0}{\lim}i\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(re^{it})dt$.
My problem is show that the function converges uniformly so i change between integral and limit

Comment: If $f$ is continuous everywhere, then it is uniformly continuous inside the disk of radius 1 about the origin (for example) and $f(re^{it}) \to f(0)$ uniformly.

Comment: **Hint:** $(r,t)\mapsto f(re^{it})$ is continuous on some compact $(r,t)\in[0,R]\times[0,2\pi]$, therefore a constant domination and making use of the Dominated Convergence Theorem should help :)

Comment: I only know that f is continuous at 0 not everywhere @HansEngler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use definition of continuity. Let any $\epsilon>0$.  There is a $\delta$ such that $|f(z)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ for all $z\in B(0,\delta)$. In particular, if $r<\delta$ you have that $|f(re^{it})-f(0)|<\epsilon$, note this is independent on the $t$ (uniform).
Use this to prove (just by limit definition) that $\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(re^{it})dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(0)dt$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $z \in \Bbb{C}$ with $|z|< \delta$, we have $|f(z) - f(0)| < \epsilon$. Now, let $0 < r < \delta$. Then,
\begin{align}
\left| \int_{|z| = r} \dfrac{f(z)}{z} \,dz - 2 \pi i f(0)\right| &= \left|i\int_0^{2 \pi}f(re^{it})\, dt - 2\pi i f(0) \right| \\
&= \left| \int_0^{2 \pi}(f(re^{it}) - f(0)) \, dt\right| \\
&\leq \int_0^{2 \pi}\left|f(re^{it}) - f(0) \right|\, dt \\
&\leq \int_0^{2 \pi} \epsilon \, dt \\
&= 2\pi \epsilon.
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, the claim is proved.